# Getting console error

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using libgdx trying to make a game, but
when I run this from the desktoplauncher, I get a error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orhantozan.game.PongMain.render(PongMain.java:216)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

What is the cause of this? I dont know what the error means :(

Core: http://pastebin.com/r74wB5xX

Desktop: http://pastebin.com/i0w4H4Wq

Dew class: http://pastebin.com/wuPnUBbg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `dewList` field gets initialized. Alternatively change

```
Array<Dew> dewList;
```

to

```
Array<Dew> dewList = new Array();
```

if possible.

Comment: That helped :) Thank you. But ppl also said that you should declare a object at the start of a class, and create an instance in the create() method. So what is the difference between yours and and creating the instance in the create() method

Comment: I've got no idea who says that (init object in the create method) but nowhere in your `create` you initialize that field (`dewList`).

Comment: Actually I posted this on reddit too and some guy just said Array<Dew> dewlist; should be in the start and dewlist = new Array<Dew>(); should be in create()